# How to create Extension which runs beforeAll only once for whole big class with many nested classes inside

Tags: java, junit5, junit5-extension-model

Given my tested class with many nested classes inside:

```
class TestWithManyNested {

    @RegisterExtension
    static MyExtension extension = new MyExtension();

    @Nested
    class Nested1 {

        @Test
        void nested1() {
        }
    }

    @Nested
    class Nested2 {

        @Test
        void nested2() {
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my simple extension:

```
static class MyExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback, BeforeEachCallback, AfterEachCallback {

        @Override
        public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("beforeAll");
        }

        @Override
        public void afterAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("afterAll");
        }
    }
```

How can I run my `TestWithManyNested` with `MyExtension` which just run `beforeAll` only once for whole test

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the class-level callbacks to execute for the outermost class, you can rewrite your extension as follows (checking that there is no "enclosing class" for the outermost class).

```java
static class MyExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {

    @Override
    public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        Class<?> testClass = extensionContext.getRequiredTestClass();
        if (testClass.getEnclosingClass() == null) {
            System.err.println("beforeAll: " + testClass.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void afterAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
        Class<?> testClass = extensionContext.getRequiredTestClass();
        if (testClass.getEnclosingClass() == null) {
            System.err.println("afterAll: " + testClass.getName());
        }
    }
}
```